# How Bundle.preferredLocalizations(from:) works

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, foundation, core-foundation

Can someone please help me understand, how [preferredLocalizations(from:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle/1417249-preferredlocalizations)  works and return locale?

For reference:
Found [this](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/Bundle.swift#L408) 
and [this](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/155f1ce1965effe55289477507a6f9fbdc8fe333/CoreFoundation/PlugIn.subproj/CFBundle_Locale.c)

I want to know the actual implementation, what is the logic behind it?
For example:
`let locale = Bundle.preferredLocalizations(from: ["en_GB", "en_CA", "en_UK", "en_US", fr_CA, jp_JP], forPreferences: ["en_IN"])`
Here it will return `en_GB` - So I want to know how and why it returned `en_GB`

Answer (score 0):

You pass in a list of all your app's supported language IDs then, based on the user's device preferences, this method returns an ordered list of the language IDs that are most appropriate for that current user, and ignores language ID's that are not applicable to that user.

This will typically have the user's selected language ID first, then a generic fallback. This method can be used to help you localise things (like images).

Comment: Thanks, @bradley-mackey.
Yes I know this but I want to know the actual implementation, what is the logic behind it?
For example:
`let locale = Bundle.preferredLocalizations(from: ["en_GB", "en_CA", "en_UK", "en_US", fr_CA, jp_JP], forPreferences: ["en_IN"])`
Here it will return `en_GB` - So I want to know how and why it returned `en_GB`